# Why doesn't ToList() work as expected?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two lists of processes and i want to get a list of their names.
The following try fails and i have no clue why!?
usually any list has an Except method which can be used to get the difference between two lists, I am trying to get a list of names and see if there are any difference between them using `Except()`.

```
var t = latesProcessList
    .Select(p=>p.ProcessName)
    .ToList()
    .Except(
        snapShotList.Select(q=>q.ProcessName).ToList() );
```

I am trying to get the new processes in a form of a list so that i can carry on my next intentions.

can someone tell me what i am missing here?

Comment: the resulting t is null!

Comment: It returns null or it is an empty enumerable

Comment: `Except` **never** returns null

Comment: @pescolino this is why I am confused

Comment: i guess its the later one. by the way i just noticed something strange! when i mouse overed the t, in the opened window, the propertiese such as first and second are null, but the time i click on the Resultview refresh button, they get populated?!!! shouldnt list() itself run ResultView?

Comment: @Hossein No, it return IEnumerable and is only evaluated when you use it

Comment: So how can i trigger it without using a loop such as foreach?

Comment: @Hossein pay attention that `t` is NOT a list. You don't call `ToList()` on the return value of `Except(..)`

Comment: @user3038092: oh yeah , thank you very much ;) i just figured it out;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `.ToList()`

```
var t = latesProcessList
.Select(p=>p.ProcessName)
.Except(snapShotList.Select(q=>q.ProcessName))
.ToList();
```

Comment: I highly doubt the first ToList calls are necessary. You could clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

`A.Except( B )` will return the items in `A` that are not in `B`.  You will need to union the results with a call to `B.Except( A )` to get all items that contained in one list and not the other.

Comment: Tanks, but why is it null then? Im only interested in items which are in A and not in B, A.Except(B) does this right?

Comment: It shouldn't be null - extreme case would be a copy of the original list or an empty list